# Destroy Session, Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've set up Devise to authenticate/register users.

But having problems signing them out.

Have this link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

It looks like this in HTML:

```
<a href="/users/sign_out">Sign Out</a>
```

When I click it - get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

Comment: Its routing as a GET when it should be a DELETE. You correctly add the `method: :delete` so I'm guessing it is a problem with your devise routing setup. Can you show that?

Comment: The first code quote shows it: link_to ... :method => :delete. Or you are asking about something else?

Comment: `method: :delete` and `:method => :delete` are identical, I was just using the shorter form. I was asking if you can show your `config/routes.rb` where you have your devise routing setup.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` in your layout file "application.html.erb."

Then, in your config -> initializers -> "devise.rb" file make sure it says:

`config.sign_out_via = :delete`

and your "sign_out" code `destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete` should work.

If it still doesn't work please comment!

Good luck.

Comment: Have two website versions. One is HTML, and one is Mobile. In :html version - you're right, I didn't have javascript_include_tag :defaults. Once I added it - it started working. But :mobile version does have this tag, and still does not sign out (same error). I followed this tutorial: [http://ponzicoder.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/rails-3-basic-scaffold-devise-authentication-action-mailer-jquery-mobile/]

Comment: I fixed it. Simply copied content of application.html.erb to application.mobile.erb. Good enough for now. Thanks!